# Prove the existence of a similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, similar-matrices, schur-decomposition

$A$, $B$ are two matrices such that $A\ge0$ and $B\ge0$ and either $A>0$ or $B>0$. I am trying to show that matrix $BA$ is similar to a matrix with non-negative diagonal elements. Here; $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices. Let's suppose the two matrices have the same size.

My Approach:
\begin{align}
BA = B^{1/2}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})B^{-1/2} && (i)
\end{align}

This is analogous to Schur decomposition; $X = SDS^{-1}$. If $B = SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $S$ is an orthogonal matrix; then (i) becomes:

$BA = (SD^{1/2}S^{-1})[(SD^{1/2}S^{-1})A(SD^{1/2}S^{-1})](SD^{-1/2}S^{-1})$

Now, if I could show that $[(SD^{1/2}S^{-1})A(SD^{1/2}S^{-1})]$ has upper-block triangular then I think it would help me answer the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with $A \ge 0$?

Comment: A is non-negative definite matrix

Comment: Every square matrix $M$ is similar to a matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $\frac 1{\operatorname{tr}(M)}$. Notably, because $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, $BA$ will have a non-negative trace and will have trace zero if and only if $BA = 0$.

Comment: suppose WLOG that $B$ is PD, then $BA$ is similar to $B^\frac{1}{2}AB^\frac{1}{2}$ which is PSD (it is congruent to $A$ after all).  All PSD matrices have non-negative diagonal elements (why?).